# Ускорить count() postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, оптимизация, select, count

Как ускорить подсчет всех строк в PostgreSQL v9.3.11?

Главное чтобы `WHERE` поддерживалось.

Сейчас скорость загрузки: 2.9424 сек. (324477 записей)

Запрос :

```
SELECT COUNT("my_field") FROM "mytable";
```

Я уже и `estimate` смотрел, и создание таблицы для записи кол-ва строк через `INSERT` + `DELETE` триггеры. Но это все не подходит, так как должна быть сортировка на странице, поэтому важен `WHERE`, а в `estimate` и прочем методе не знаю как использовать это.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как ускорить подсчет строк в таблице с учетом `WHERE`?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting оно самое

Comment: вообще не подходит, читал я это

Comment: А почему count("my_field") вам реально надо узнать сколько в этой колонке not null значений. Смотрите план выполнения. Для условия where должен существовать индекс. И надо писать count(1) если вам нужно именно кол-во строк а не not null значений